# Does sqlalchemy preserve order in many-to-one/many-to-many relationships?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy (with sqlite for now, but this may change later) to build a database in which order of insertions and thus rowids is important. I basically have the following:

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement':True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    refs = relationship('Ref')

class Ref(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'refs'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement':True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    message_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('messages.id'))
```

When I create a `Message` object and `append` a `Ref` object to `message.refs`, I'd like to be sure that when I commit this to the database the `Ref`s will be inserted in the same order in which they appear in the list. Does sqlalchemy do this by default or do I need to flush after each append?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**: even if in in your simple case it would probably work this way, [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) does not make any guarantee regarding the order of insertion.

---

If you really need the `rowids` to be *globally* ordered as requested, there is no *simple* way of making it work out-of-the box.

However, if what you need is **ordering of `Ref` within the `Message`**, then this can be achieved by adding another column to `Ref` for indicating the ordering, in which case using the [Ordering List](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) extension is the easiest way to achieve this. This will do both loading and inserting of `Ref` objects keeping the ordering.

Comment: Right. My 5¢: for many-to-many you'll need an intermediate model with ordering field, relationship to it, and association proxy to hide these implementation details.

Comment: Thanks van, that looks perfect for what I need :)